# Why 3T APS pixel implements a NMOS reset transistor instead of a PMOS?

Tags: cmos, image-sensor, pixels

I'm very curious about why the 3T APS píxel sensor implements an NMOS reset transistor.
As it is well-known, we will have a voltage of Vdd-Vth during the reset phase. This situation will imply higher FPN, thus the initial integration voltage will be highly dependent on Vth.
If we replaced it with a PMOS transistor, we always would be reset to Vdd.

[image]

Comment: Although beneficial for image lag reduction, the use of PMOS instead of NMOS doubles the reset noise power. To reconcile the image lag and low-power requirements, 6T-cell solutions exist, combining hard and soft resets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although beneficial for image lag reduction, the use of PMOS instead of NMOS doubles the reset noise power. To reconcile the image lag and low-power requirements, 6T-cell solutions exist, combining hard and soft resets.